# Get event inside of EventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The following code doesn't work:

```
slider.prototype.onTransitionEnd = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.slideElement.addEventListener(self.startEvent, function() { self.onTouchStart(/* e, event or what? */ }, false); 
}

slider.prototype.onTouchStart = function(e) {
alert(e);
//HERE I NEED THE EVENT, HOW CAN I GET THIS?
}
```

The problem is, that I cannot access to the event inside the function `onTouchStart`.
By default, the event automatically transferred:

```
function onTransitionEnd() {
  slide.addEventListener(startEvent, onTouchStart, false);
}
function onTouchStart(e) {
alert(e) /* IT WORK'S! */
}
```

But how does it work in my example?

Comment: Ah, i believe i have found the solution:

function() { self.onTouchStart(window.event) }

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a parenthesis. Could that be what's wrong?

```
slider.prototype.onTransitionEnd = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.slideElement.addEventListener(self.startEvent, function() { self.onTouchStart(/* e, event or what? */) }, false); 
}

slider.prototype.onTouchStart = function(e) {
    alert(e);
    //HERE I NEED THE EVENT, HOW CAN I GET THIS?
}
```